# Maven: How to specify Javac plugin argument with maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, javac, javac-compiler-plugin

Javac provides the following nonstandard option (from "javac -X" command line help):

```
-Xplugin:"name args"       Name and optional arguments for a plug-in to be run
```

However, Maven does not handle that format.  For example, the following does not work:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-Xplugin:"Manifold static"</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've tried several different variations and tried replacing the space with '=', still no bueno.  Is there a workaround?

Note I am using the [Manifold](http://manifold.systems/) javac plugin with Java 8. Reproducing is simple.. create a pom with a dependency on the manifold-all jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>systems.manifold</groupId>
  <artifactId>manifold-all</artifactId>
  <version>0.9-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

You don't really need any source, this is just to demonstrate that Maven will not accept the `-Xplugin:"Manifold static"` javac argument.

Also note Java 9 appears to have changed the format of `-Xplugin` to no longer require quotes. See the [Java 9 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627) on this.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the space?

Comment: @Andrey Haha, yes it's my project, it's in an alpha stage right now.  I'm not sure where or how that test dependency is in play.  Can you provide your pom file so I can reproduce that?

Comment: You should be able to use the plugin with the default `-Xplugin:Manifold` javac argument with the base jar file dependency:

`<dependency>
  <groupId>systems.manifold</groupId>
  <artifactId>manifold</artifactId>
  <version>0.9-alpha</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Also, you don't really need to "use" the plugin in your project so much as simply try to compile it with Maven and see the error regarding the `-Xplugin:"Manifold static"` argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165087/discussion-between-scott-mckinney-and-andrey-tyukin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In light of this discussion: [MCOMPILER-178](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-178) and this patch: [pull request](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/pull/4), and since a space doesn't seem to be a character allowed in XML-names, I would suspect that you have to just drop all the double-quotes, and keep all the spaces.

This here:

```
myOption=foo"bar"baz
```

is string concatenation in `bash` (or whatever shell your are using). It stores the string "foobarbaz" in variable `myOption`. If you use double quotes in an option in `bash`, then it simply means: "bash, please treat the entire thing between the quotes as a single argument, don't split it into an array of string arguments". For example, if you run the following
bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

with these arguments:

```
$ ./testArgs.sh hello -World:"blah blah blah" foobar
```

you will get this output:

```
hello
-World:blah blah blah
foobar
```

The `-World:blah blah blah` part is a single string, the quotes are not preserved.

Maven is not bash. POM is an XML file, it has tags, some of the tags are filled with text. XML doesn't care about bash's syntax for string concatenation or argument-parsing. If I understood the above discussion correctly, they passed the content of the xml-tags directly to the compiler, without any modifications.

Therefore, my best guess would be to just drop the double quotes:

```
<arg>-Xplugin:MyPlugin myArg</arg>
```

If this doesn't help, then I misunderstood the discussion linked above entirely, or maybe you are using a maven version that works differently.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, thanks, however I've tried that and many other variations without luck.  The discussion you mention concerns `<compilerArguments>`, which is different from `<compilerArgs>`, but still fails in a similar way.

Comment: @ScottMcKinney The discussion was about `<compilerArguments>` (which turned out to be awkward), and this is why `<compilerArgs>` were introduced. If my proposal doesn't work, then I have to agree that it seems to be quite counter-intuitive. Is there a way to make your problem reproducible, i.e. specify maven version, the specific compiler plugin, and the exact content of `<arg>`? If it's your own plugin, maybe it could be somehow reduced into a trivial no-op compiler plugin? It's weird, because all text (including whitespace) should be passed to the `javac` unchanged...

Comment: Yeah, it is weird.  I'm using the [Manifold](http://manifold.systems/) plugin. Reproducing is simple.. create a pom with a dependency on the manifold-all jar (and tools.jar if using Java 8).  Then add the maven-compiler-plugin example above.  I'm currently using Maven 3.5.0.  The problem goes away with the standard Manifold plugin setting: `-Xplugin:Manifold`, but I'd like a way to use the `static` argument if possible.

Comment: @ScottMcKinney I won't be able to try it today, it's getting late in this part of the world... Could you please add this information to your original question (there is a little gray 'edit' button under it). The link to `Manifold` is particularly useful, because this makes the question reproducible, that's good! I'm playing with the thought that I could create `javac-compiler-plugin` tag extra for that, otherwise this question goes under in all the "maven-compiler-plugin"-hits. But, tomorrow... ;)

Comment: @ScottMcKinney It would also be very helpful if you could describe more precisely what "no bueno" means: does `mvn` complain, or does `javac` complain, or does the plugin itself complain? Or does the compiler plugin simply ignore the parameters? (I'll find out tomorrow, but it's probably helpful for those who will come here with a similar problem).

Comment: Done.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks to @Andry for his assistance, the problem turned out to be specific to my environment (not sure exactly what however). Afterward, the argument works by dropping the quotes.

Comment: As a tangential: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795733/prevent-maven-shade-plugin-from-exposing-system-dependency