# Prevent maven-shade-plugin from exposing <system> dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

Thanks to a separate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715546/maven-how-to-specify-javac-plugin-argument-with-maven-compiler-plugin), I realized my project's uber-jar had a bug. I create the uber-jar using `maven-shade-plugin` because I need the more advanced transformer capabilities to merge several ServiceLoader definitions.

So, the issue is that my project has a system-scope compile-time dependency on `tools.jar`, locating `tools.jar` on the local machine relative to the value of the `java.home` sysprop. The bug is that I didn't realize this dependency was:

1. leaking into the dependency-reduced `pom.xml` of the uber-jar, and
2. even worse, the pattern `${java.home}` in the dependency definition was being resolved and hard-coded into the uber-jar's POM. This second part was particularly embarrassing as it reveals the JDK location of the build machine (see line 50 [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/systems/manifold/manifold-all/0.9-alpha/manifold-all-0.9-alpha.pom)).

To workaround this problem, I conditionally disabled the profile which created the dependency. All details below are in the `<activation>` section:

Before:

```
<profile>
  <id>internal.tools-jar</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

After:

```
<profile>
  <id>internal.tools-jar</id>
  <activation>
    <jdk>1.8</jdk>
    <file>
      <missing>src/main/java/systems/manifold/Dummy.java</missing> <!-- this file is only present in the uber-jar module, therefore exclude if present -->
    </file>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

So, after all that, my question is: is this the best way to prevent this system-scoped dependency from leaking into the uber-jar's dependency-reduced `pom.xml`?

Thanks in advance,

Kyle

Updated 2018-02-16:

Unfortunately the following configuration in the shade plugin doesn't prevent the system-scope dependency from leaking:

```
<artifactSet>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>*</exclude>
  </excludes>
</artifactSet>
```

to the shade plugin's configuration but the resolved system scope dependency still shows up in the POM. Puzzling!

Comment: It's a while since I used shade, but think you can put some excludes in an <artifactSet> - [example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately no luck.